# Compiled underscore JST reference flags underscore not defined error?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, browserify, underscore.js-templating

I'm using compiled underscore templates in my Backbone build with Browserify. When I reference the template and run my code I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined` and I'm not completely sure why, can anyone advise?

**JS**

```
var Backbone = require('backbone'),
    $ = require('jquery'),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    dataStore = require('dataStore'),
    FastDOM = require('fastdom');

require('../templates');

module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({

    className: 'contact-view view transition-toggle is-hidden',

    template: JST['contact.html'],
//...
```

Offending underscore line `_.escape,Array.prototype.join}with(obj)`